# Error in Declaring Non-Optional Map Property in Realm Swift Object

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I have this realm object with a map property:

```
class UserModel: Object {
       @Persisted var uploadMap = Map<String, UploadingModel>()
}
```

where UploadingModel is another realm object.

once I ran the app I got this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException',
reason: 'Map<String, UploadingModel> property 
'uploadMap' must be marked as optional.'
```

In the official documentation: [realm-swift](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/model-data/supported-types/#map-dictionary) there is an example that initialize the map like the above without marking it as optional.
Also, I use other realm types like `List<UploadingModel>()` and no error is thrown.

How can I avoid mark it as optional and why the error is thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Super good question and the documentation is a little thin in this area.

Here's why

TL;DR

> If the value part of a Map is a Realm Object, it can be nil so it
> must be optional

Long explanation via an example:

Start with a Dog Class and then a Class that holds all dog locations as a Map

```
class Dog: Object {
    @Persisted var name: String
}

class AllDogLocations: Object {
   @Persisted var dogLocation = Map<String, Dog?>() //note optional dog here
}
```

and then say there two dogs are persisted in Realm, Spot and Scraps and they are added to a dog locations object which is also persisted. Spot is in Ohio and Scraps is in Florida

```
let spotDog = Dog()
spotDog.name = "Spot"

let scrapsDog = Dog()
scrapsDog.name = "Scraps"

let all = AllDogLocations()
all.dogLocation["Ohio"] = spotDog
all.dogLocation["Florida"] = scrapsDog

try! realm.write {
    realm.add(all)
}
```

Image then, elsewhere in the app that Spot is deleted from Realm

```
let spotDog = realm.objects(Dog.self).where { $0.name == "Spot" }.first!
try! realm.write {
    realm.delete(spotDog)
}
```

What then happens to the AllDogsLocations? Here's what it then looks like

```
AllDogLocations {
    dogLocation = Map<string, Dog> <0x600003dd1810> (
    [Florida]: Dog {
            name = Scraps;
        },
    [Ohio]: <null>
    );
}
```

Note Spot, which used to be in Ohio, the value is nil because the object no longer exists. It's key in the map however, is left intact.

However, what would happen if the Value (Dog) was required to not be nil and then that dog was deleted from Realm

```
Map<String, Dog>()
```

Whoops - there's your problem! It must be optional because it COULD be deleted elsewhere in the app!

Note that in the case of <String, String>, setting the String to nil removes the map entry entirely as that value is required (non-optional)

There is some debate on the current behavior; what *should* happen if the Object is set to nil. Let it be nil? Remove it? See [Effect of Deleting an Object in a Map?](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/effect-of-deleting-an-object-in-a-map/246664)

And if you are using Realm Sync this Git post is very important [Map: Remove Keys When Object Values Become nil #8379](https://github.com/realm/realm-swift/issues/8379)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer @jay.  Just to make sure, if the value is not a Realm object, does it still need to be optional? Are there any restrictions on the map's value being a struct or a class?

Comment: @MSm The value can be a Realm Object subclass or one of the following types: Bool, Int, Int8, Int16, Int32, Int64, Float, Double, String, Data, Date, Decimal128, and ObjectId, and then the and their optional version of each. There are additional restrictions if this is a sync'd realm as well.